# ECS task definition - Set memory and cpu ratio on containers

Tags: amazon-ecs

below is the snippet from my terraform AWS ECS Task definition:

```
container_definitions = jsonencode([
{
  essential   = true
  memory      = <...here...>
  cpu         = <...here...>
  name        = "mongodb"
  image       = ...
},
{
  name             = "engine"
  memory      = <...here...>
  cpu         = <...here...>
  dependsOn = [
    {
      containerName = "mongodb"
      condition     = "START"
    }
  ]
  image = ...
}
```

This task definition is used to deploy services in ECS where I have multiple Capacity Providers.

These capacity providers manages EC2 instances created from AWS Launch Templates, where the launch templates differ only in the instance type, like

1. t2.micro
2. t2.large
3. ...

Factoids:

- **All of these configuration is deployed via Terraform**
- **AWS instance: their number and their type comes from AWS System Parameter**

**Question**

Is it possible and how to describe in the task definition, that e.g. mongodb container has 30% of total RAM and CPU, while engine has the rest?

No matter what is the instance type under the service task, I want only control, the ratio of memory and CPU consumption of the underlying EC2 instance under my task